# why mutable objects having same value have different id in Python

Tags: python

Thank you for your valuable time, I have just started learning Python. I came across Mutable and Immutable objects.
As far as I know mutable objects can be changed after their creation.

```
a = [1,2,3]
print(id(a))
45809352
a = [3,2,1]
print(id(a))
52402312
```

Then why id of the same list "a" gets changed when its values are changed.

Comment: Assignment isn't mutation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why two individually created immutable objects have same id and mutable objects have different while both refer to same values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091568/why-two-individually-created-immutable-objects-have-same-id-and-mutable-objects)

Comment: @Kevin thank you. Now I understand the concept of mutation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your interpretation is incorrect.

When you assign a new `list` to `a`, you change its reference.

On the other hand you could do:

```
a[:] = [3,2,1]
```

and then the reference would not change.

Answer (score 0):

*mutable* means that the *content* of the object is changed. for example `a.append(4)` actually make `a` equal to `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, while on the contrary, appending to a string (which is immutable) does not change it, it creates a new one.

However, when you re-assign, you create a new object and assign it to `a`, you don't alter the existing content of `a`. The previous content is lost (unless refered-to by some other variable)

Comment: You comparison to "appending to a string" is not so good, because a string does not have an `append` method. You can only do `string + "foo"`, which will create a new string, but so does `[1,2,3] + [4]`. `str.replace` might be a better example.

Comment: @tobias_k: ok, did not mean it literally, just wanted to convey the idea. In other languages there is an append, but still the main idea it the creation of a new object

Answer (score 0):

If you change a list, its id doesn't change. But you may do things that instead create a new list, and then it will also have a new id.

E.g.,

```
>>> l=[]
>>> id(l)
140228658969920
>>> l.append(3)  # Changes l
>>> l
[3]
>>> id(l)
140228658969920  # Same ID
>>> l = l + [4]  # Computes a new list that is the result of l + [4], assigns that
>>> l
[3, 4]
>>> id(l)
140228658977608  # ID changed
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
a = [3, 2, 1]
```

1. You unlink the list of [1, 2, 3] from variable `a`.
2. Create a new list [3, 2, 1] then assign it to `a` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Being immutable doesn't mean you assign a new object, it means your original object can be changed "in place" for example via `.append()`

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3]
>>> id(my_list)
140532335329544
>>> my_list.append(5)
>>> id(my_list)
140532335329544
>>> my_list[3] = 4
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> id(my_list)
140532335329544
```